# Terminator doesn't show System Title Bar

Tags: system, terminator

after I reboot my system for some updates, my Terminator stopped showing the system tool bars... Anyone knows why?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 1. do other applications got system title? if not then gtk-window-decorator is not started. if yes, then maybe Terminator is misplaced by window/compositing manager. <Win key>+left mouse button can move your Terminator window,

Comment: all other applications are ok... I moved the window and continues to not show the toolbar. It actually doesnt have any title bar

Answer (score 25):

GUI-solution:

Right-click anywhere in Terminator window and select **Preferenes**.

Check **Window borders** option and restart Terminator.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was to edit ~/.config/terminator/config and comment out the line

```
borderless = True
```

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks. Terminator must have been updated yesterday and added this config, for last night it was alright and today, when I turned my computer on, it was like this.

Answer (score 0):

For me,  "borderless = True" made no difference, because I had terminator config files, which overwrite the standard config file: "~/.config/terminator/config

Just pressing **CTRL+U** did the trick for me. It re-activated the top bar again!

This is my personal terminator-keybinding for Group/Ungroup all terminals (group_all_toggle).

Give it a try! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have set your right click to paste content in Terminator terminal you will need to double click your middle button(scroller button) in mouse to open preferences. Else press options button in your keyboard placed somewhere near your right-ctrl or right alt buttons(varies according to laptop brands).